# Bash script to Add a new key value pair dynamically in Json

Tags: json, jq

My JSON file is,

```json
{
  "student1": {
    "Name": "Caroline",
    "Age": "24",
    "email": "Caroline123@gmail.com",
    "Phone": "1234567890",
    "Blood group": "O+ve"
  }
}
```

My desired output is,

```json
{
  "student1": {
    "Name": "Caroline",
    "Age": "24",
    "email": "Caroline123@gmail.com",
    "Phone1": "1234567890",
    "Phone2": "1267345980",
    "Phone3": "9865432130",
    "Blood group": "O+ve"
  }
}
```

The new key-value pairs **Phone1**, **Phone2** and **Phone3** , whose values are stored in the array called VALUES, needs to be added in the place of the key **Phone**

```
m=1
for i in ${VALUES[@]}
do
  jq --arg newval "$i" '.student1 += { VALUES$m: $newval }' <<<"$filepath"
  let "m += 1"
done
```

Above is my code, But it's not working!
Can anyone please help me to get the desired output!

Comment: Where does the additional information come from? Also, since SO is not a "free programming service", questions should show some research effort, e.g. in the form of failed attempts.

Comment: Yes, I edited the question, Please have a look at the question again!

Comment: Your JSON isn't valid.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `+=` operator such as

```
jq '.student1 += { "Phone2": "1267345980", "Phone3": "9865432130" }'
```

and rename existing key `Phone` to `Phone1` by using

```
jq --sort-keys '.student1 += { "Phone2": "1267345980", "Phone3": "9865432130" }| .[] | .["Phone1"] = .Phone | del(.Phone) | {"Student1" : . }'
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/y3372pSPgO)</kbd>

**Edit**( *due to your last edit* ): Considering you have an array `VALUES` such as

```
$ declare -p VALUES
declare -a VALUES='([0]="\"1267345980\"" [1]="\"9865432130\"")'
```

and have a JSON file named `Students.json`, then use

```
m=2
for i in "${VALUES[@]}" 
do  
  cat <<< $(jq '.student1 += { "Phone'"${m}"'" : '"${i}"'}' Students.json) > Students.json
  let "m += 1"   
done
```

in order to add the elements with keys `Phone2` and `Phone3` taken from the array

P.S.: *tested on GNU/Linux*